# Find XML file with specific path

Tags: bash, grep, xml, locate, file-search

I'm working with XML files, each of which could be dozens of lines long. There are literally hundreds of these files, all over a directory structure. Yes, it is Magento.

I need to find the file that has the `<foo><bar><boom><bang>` element. A `<boom><bang>` tag could be defined under other tags, so **I need to search for the full path** not just the end tag or tags. There could be dozens of lines between each tag, and other tags between them:

```
<foo>
  <hello_world>
... 50 lines ....
  </hello_world>
  <bar>
    <giraffe>
... 50 lines ....
    </giraffe>
    <boom>
      <bang>Vital information here</bang>
    </boom>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

**What is the elegant, *nix way of searching for the file that defines `<foo><bar><boom><bang>`?** I'm currently on an up-to-date Debian-derived distro.

This is my current solution, which is far from eloquent:

```
$ grep -rA 100 foo * | grep -A 100 bar | grep -A 100 boom | grep bang | grep -E 'foo|bar|boom|bang'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `xmlstarlet` to `sel`ect `i`f the path exists then output the `f`ilename:

```
find . -name '*.xml' -exec xmlstarlet sel -t -i '/foo/bar/boom/bang' -f -n {} +
```

Comment: @dotancohen bear in mind I'm a beginner with xml/xmlstarlet and there may be things wrong with this approach...

Comment: Certainly, but they're far less wrong than my current grep-based solution. If I improve on this I'll add a comment or edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Using `xq` XML parser tool from the [`yq` installation package](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) and print the filename only when exit status was 0 based on the xq output.

```
find -type f -name '*.xml' -exec sh -c '
    xq -e '.foo.bar.boom.bang' "$1" >/dev/null
' _ {} \; -print
```

---

> -e               set the exit status code based on the output;

---

from the `man jq` for more details about this option:

> -e / --exit-status:
> Sets  the  exit  status of jq to 0 if the last output values was neither false nor null, 1 if the last output value was
> either false or null, or 4 if no valid result was ever produced. Normally jq exits with 2 if there was any usage  problem or system error, 3 if there was a jq program compile error, or 0 if the jq program ran.

Comment: Thank you, `xy` seems a very useful tool! I have used `jq` in the past. Is there a way to add wildcards in the element tree, i.e. `.foo.*.bang` (example which does not work)? Googling I don't see a simple solution, but if you know offhand than I would appreciate it. **Thank you.**

Comment: @dotancohen I'm not much familiar in these commands just a little bit I know, by cases whenever I see questions like this I'm going looking into their man pages to see if there are relevant things there that can resolve asker question or not. I'm not sure if these commands can supports wildcards or not, but I know it has some functions for regex matching but never used them. you may also have a look there too. and you are welcome! that's also `xq`, `yq` not `xy` by the way.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I did check before asking, but the best that I found [was a complicated workaround for jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/82).

Comment: @dotancohen see also here https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE for regex matching in jq, which I think it should apply in `xq` too (again didn't test or used before)